# Parse negative number with parentheses

Tags: java, parsing

How to convert a string "(123,456)" to -123456 (negative number) in java?

Ex:

(123,456) = -123456

123,456   = 123456

I used NumberFormat class but it is converting positive numbers only, not working with negative numbers.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
try {
       System.out.println(" number formatted to " + numberFormat.parse("123,456"));
       System.out.println(" number formatted to " + numberFormat.parse("(123,456)"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
           System.out.println("I couldn't parse your string!");
    }
```

Output:

number formatted to 123456

I couldn't parse your string!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try :

```
    try {
        boolean hasParens = false;
        String s = "123,456";
        s = s.replaceAll(",","")

        if(s.contains("(")) {
            s = s.replaceAll("[()]","");
            hasParens = true;
        }

        int number = Integer.parseInt(s);

        if(hasParens) {
            number = -number;
        }
    } catch(...) {
    }
```

There might be a better solution though

Comment: You need to check for the existence of parens before setting it to be negative.

Comment: Oups, I hadn't seen that part. I fixed but there is probably a better solution

Comment: You could use s.replaceAll("[(),]", "") to replace all at once.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know. Taken into account :-)

Answer (score 8):

Simple trick without custom parsing logic:

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0;(#,##0)", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US)).parse("(123,456)")
```

DecimalFormatSymbols parameter could be omitted for case to use current locale for parsing

Answer (score 6):

Not same API, but worth trying

```
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)");
    myFormatter.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) myFormatter.parse("(1000,001)");
    System.out.println(result);         
    System.out.println(myFormatter.parse("1000,001"));
```

outputs:

*-1000001* and *1000001*

Answer (score 2):

I have an other solution :

```
    String s = "123,456";
    Boolean parenthesis = s.contains("(");

    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    Object eval = mgr.eval(s);

    if(eval instanceof Double){
        int result = (int) ((Double)eval) * 1000;
        result *= (parenthesis ? -1 : 1);
   }
```

It is an atypical solution, even if there is a duplicate post, i think this answer is worth it :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String negative = "(123,456)";
    String positive = "123,456";

    System.out.println("negative: " + parse(negative));
    System.out.println("positive: " + parse(positive));
}

private static Integer parse(String parsed) {
    if (parsed.contains("(") || parsed.contains(")")) {
        parsed = parsed.replaceAll("[(),]", "");
        return Integer.valueOf(parsed) * -1;
    } else {
        parsed = parsed.replaceAll("[,]", "");
        return Integer.valueOf(parsed);
    }
}
```

Output will be:

negative: -123456
 positive: 123456

Answer (score 2):

Here, I'm trying to change the  string to integer, and then back to integer to string.

Double slashes ('\\') are used for escaping the special character, if there are multiple occurrences they are useful.

Here is the complete piece of code : Tested and Executed.

```
    package com.siri;

    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;

    /* Java program to demonstrate how to implement static and non-static
       classes in a java program. */
    class NumberFormat
    {        
       // How to create instance of static and non static nested class?
       public static void main(String args[])
       {        
          NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
          try 
          {
             System.out.println(" number formatted to " + 
                                numberFormat.parse("123,456"));

             String numberToBeChanged="(123,456)";
             if(numberToBeChanged.contains("(") || 
                numberToBeChanged.contains(")"))
             {
                numberToBeChanged=numberToBeChanged.replaceAll("\\(", 
                "").replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll(",", "");

                int numberToBeChangedInt = Integer.parseInt(numberToBeChanged);
                numberToBeChangedInt *= -1;
                numberToBeChanged = Integer.toString(numberToBeChangedInt);
             }

             System.out.println(" number formatted to " + 
                                numberFormat.parse(numberToBeChanged));

             } 
             catch (ParseException e) 
             {
                System.out.println("I couldn't parse your string!");
             }
        }
    }
```

Now you see the expected results as specified.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int getIntValue(String numberToParse) {
    if (numberToParse.contains("(")) {
        numberToParse = numberToParse.replaceAll("[(),]", "");
        return Integer.valueOf(numberToParse) * -1;
    } else {
        numberToParse = numberToParse.replaceAll("[,]", "");
        return Integer.valueOf(numberToParse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that only strings with the given format appear, then why not simply replace the leading "(" by a minus sign and the final ")" by nothing before parsing as in:

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = DecimalFormat.getInstance();

String number = "(123,456)";
System.out.println(" number formatted to " + 
                     numberFormat.parse(number.replaceAll("(","-").replace All(")","")));
```

Comment: This is not foolproof. It removes the negativity from the original string. Parens mean negative.

Comment: Ah, I see. `NumberFormat` apparently cannot deal with negative numbers. But using `DecimalFormat` instead should make it work, right?

Comment: I missed the part where you replaced the left paren with a hyphen. But I am not sure if you also need to remove the comma.

Comment: DecimalFormat is able to deal with the commas. They are by default treated as Grouping separators http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try it this way:

```
private static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\()?(\\d+.*)(\\))?");

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(parseLong("123,456"));
    System.out.println(parseLong("(123,456)"));
}

private static long parseLong(String string) throws ParseException {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        long value = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).parse(matcher.group(2)).longValue();
        return matcher.group(1) != matcher.group(3) ? value = -value : value;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number format " + string);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 123456
-123456
```

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive what you need with:

```
    try {
        String var = "(123,456)";
        Integer i = -Integer.parseInt(var.replaceAll("\\(", "")
                .replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\\)", ""));
        System.out.println("Integer: " + i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume the string is negative. If you just replace the left paren with a hyphen, it is safer.

Comment: I'm not assuming the string is negative I'm negating it because it is requested :)

Comment: If you look at OP's example, he is passing in two String's - one negative, one non-negative. This could be generalized into a function that handles both easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private int getInt(String s) {
    return s.contains("(") ? 
        -1 * Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[(),]","")) : 
            Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[,]",""));
}
```

This will check if the string contains a "(". If so, it will remove all '(' and ')' characters, convert the string to an integer and make the value negative. Otherwise, it removes the ',' character and parses the integer, thus being positive.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about your code, and it'll solve the problem?

Comment: explaination has been added. I believe it solves the problem.